# Getting same background and length for two columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the main content area and the sidebar to have the same background and the same height. I thought it would work if I the both sub-classes in the same `<div>`, but obviously it doesn't work. Is there a simple way to achieve this, or do I have to go for some of the faux column trickery?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="content">This is the main area</div>
        <div class="sidebar">This is the sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        The footer;
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ff1;
}

#wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

#nav {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

#main {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

.content, .sidebar {
float: left;
padding: 20px;
}

.content {
width: 510px;   
}

.sidebar {
width: 210px;
}

#footer {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
clear:both;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SorenRomer/3Jxuu/)

Comment: Via CSS you can't you need to put the same height in both with JS. Do you need help w/ that?

Comment: Yeah, please. I'm quite new to JS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapping container ( #main ) doesn't expand to the height of the child elements, because they both are floated. You could add a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix/8554054) or just

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the #main element.

Comment: Oh and I suggest to avoid using IDs as selectors in CSS, see e.g. http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

Answer (score 0):

In the jsfiddle, it seems that they do have the same height and background.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: The problem is that I want the semi-transparent background. Now, I could add that to the content and sidebar, but the height will differ as soon as more lines of text are added to one or the other...